# How to access Factory value in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm pretty new to RSpec, and I've hit a stumbling block which is probably really simple!

The action is that when the "Approve Band" link is clicked, the value of @band.validated should not be nil any more, I've got it working in my rails app, but can't get the test to work..

What am I missing?

```
  describe "edit band via admin" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:band) { FactoryGirl.create(:band) }

    before do
      admin_sign_in user
      visit edit_admin_band_path(band)
    end

    describe "approve band" do
      before { click_link "Approve Band" }
      its(@band.validated) { should_not be_nil }
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload `band` to reflect changes in the database.

```
describe "approve band" do
  before do
    click_link "Approve Band"
    band.reload
  end

  subject { band }
  its(:validated) { should_not be_nil }
end
```

Comment: @Advocation: it's my pleasure.